# Insert DATE to MySQL DB - Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get an error when i try to string replace the date and save it in the `mySQL` db. The reason is the format of the `DATE` field. i have added my `PHP` code, and `mySQL` error message below.

```
$nowDate = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['datenow']); 

echo $nowDate;
```

Output > `08-15-2012` , I am inserting this record to the database, but the `MySQL` database requires the format `yyyy-mm-dd` (`2012-08-15`) or else i get an error

```
Unable1 to run query:Incorrect date value: '08-15-2012' for column 'now_date' at row 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error specifies, the format of the date needs to be `yyyy-mm-dd`.

You can format it prior to inserting it with [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$nowDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datenow']));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$nowDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['datenow']));
```

Or better yet, if you are just trying to add the current date, let MySQL do it for you like this.  This eliminate the need to sanitize the input data.

```
INSERT INTO table SET date_field = NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

So... what's the problem? You've already said you know MySQL requires a certain format, but want to use a format that's not supported. If you insist on using your 'bad' format, then investigate using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) within your insert query, or convert your PHP string into a valid MySQL date format.

Comment: I was just about to post this. Not sure why someone voted you down.